# How to make sure client close socket first using boost asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

A server reads 10 bytes from client and write back 10 bytes, here's the code:

server:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;
namespace ba=boost::asio;

#define SERVER_PORT 12345
#define DATA_LEN 10


struct session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
    tcp::socket socket_;
    boost::asio::steady_timer timer_;
    boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> strand_;

    explicit session(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, tcp::socket socket)
    : socket_(std::move(socket)),
      timer_(io_context),
      strand_(io_context.get_executor())
    { }

    void go()
    {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        boost::asio::spawn(strand_, [this, self](boost::asio::yield_context yield)
        {
            spawn(yield, [this, self](ba::yield_context yield) {
                timer_.expires_from_now(10s); // 10 second
                while (socket_.is_open()) {
                    boost::system::error_code ec;
                    timer_.async_wait(yield[ec]);
                    // timeout triggered, timer was not canceled
                    if (ba::error::operation_aborted != ec) {
                        socket_.close();
                    }
                }
            });

            try
            {
                // read 10 bytes
                string packet;
                boost::system::error_code ec;
                ba::async_read(socket_,
                               ba::dynamic_buffer(packet),
                               ba::transfer_exactly(DATA_LEN),
                               yield[ec]);


                // write 10 bytes
                static string pkt(10, 'a');
                boost::system::error_code ecw;
                boost::asio::write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(pkt), ecw);
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                cout << "exception" << endl;
            }

            // Sleep(1000); // any better way than Sleep?
            timer_.cancel();
            socket_.close();
        });

    }
};

int main() {
    ba::io_context io_context;
    auto worker = ba::make_work_guard(io_context);

    std::thread([&]()
    {
        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context,
        tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), SERVER_PORT));

        for (;;)
        {
            boost::system::error_code ec;

            tcp::socket socket(io_context);
            acceptor.accept(socket, ec);
            if (!ec) {
                std::make_shared<session>(io_context, std::move(socket))->go();
            } 
        }
    }).detach();

    io_context.run();
}
```

The Client send 10 bytes to server and receive 10 bytes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
using namespace std;

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
namespace ba=boost::asio;

#define SERVER "11.22.33.44" // replace with your external ip address
#define PORT "12345"


static string pkt = "1234567890"; // 10 bytes

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;

    while(1) {
        getchar();

        try {
            tcp::socket s(io_context);
            tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
            boost::asio::connect(s, resolver.resolve(SERVER, PORT));

            // write 10 bytes
            boost::system::error_code ecw;
            ba::write(s, ba::buffer(pkt), ecw);

            // read 10 bytes
            string packet;
            boost::system::error_code ec;
            ba::read(s,
                   ba::dynamic_buffer(packet),
                   ba::transfer_exactly(10),
                   ec);

            // client close socket first
            {
                boost::system::error_code ec;
                s.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);
                s.close();
            }
        } catch (...) {
            cout << "exception" << endl;
        }

        cout << "done" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Problem**: The server closes the socket before the client, which causes lots of `TIME_WAIT` on server side. How to make sure that client closes socket first? I tried to `Sleep(1000)` on server side before closing socket, it seems to work, but is there any better way ?

Comment: Why not simply keep the socket open until the remote end closes it? When the remote end closes the socket, your end will become readable and a "read" operation would return with zero bytes read.

Comment: Add version of boost,compiler. Not able to compile code with `gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0` and `boost-1.65.1`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Thanks. I tried `while(1) { async_read(100_bytes); }` after the real job, until exception occur then close the socket, seems works fine :)